# RoR ActiveRecord Join Help for semi AI App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on a RoR app. Think Tinder for art with a little basic AI. As you like or dislike art the app will show you art that you will hopefully like more based on other users’ preferences. I am working on the code to pick the next image to show.

I use the following models:

Basic user info:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artworks
  has_many :artists
  has_many :art_views
end
```

Info about each piece (price, height, width, etc)

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :art_views
end
```

To represent which art has been show to a user (boolean liked indicates if the user liked the artwork)

```
class ArtView < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artwork
end
```

The logic is simple: after finding the last Artwork liked by current_user (in ArtView), find other Users who also liked the same Artwork (also in ArtView) then find new Artwork liked by those other Users that has not been seen by the current_user (no record in ArtView)

I am using the following join:

```
@artwork = Artwork.joins(:artview)
  .where(:artviews => { :liked => true})
  .where(:artviews => { :artwork_id => @artwork_id})
  .where.not(:artviews => { user_id: @id })
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't join 'Artwork' to association named 'artview'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Much appreciate any guidance/suggestions (both in fixing the error and/or improving the logic, in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ArtView has many ArtViews, so you have to reference that relationship when using `joins`.

It should work like this:

```
Artwork.joins(:art_views)
```

The same when using the `join`ed columns (no matter the kind of relationship), you should use the "real" name of the table;  it's pluralized way - that's how Rails name the tables it creates, unless otherwise specified:

```
Artwork
  .joins(:art_views)
  .where(:art_views => { :liked => true})
  .where(:art_views => { :artwork_id => @artwork_id})
  .where.not(:art_views => { user_id: @id })
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed it. Hopefully the logic I'm working on is the way to go.